# Convert scientific notation string into int

Tags: python

How would I convert:

```
s='8.833167174e+11' (str)
==> 883316717400 (int)
```

I tried doing `int(s)` or some other 'casting' but it wasn't effective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your string is a float digit you need to first convert it to `float`:

```
>>> int(float(s))
883316717400
```

> [`float([x])`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#float)
>
> Return a floating point number constructed from a number or string x.
>
> If the argument is a string, it must contain a possibly signed decimal or floating point number, possibly embedded in whitespace. The argument may also be [+|-]nan or [+|-]inf. Otherwise, the argument may be a plain or long integer or a floating point number, and a floating point number with the same value (within Python’s floating point precision) is returned. If no argument is given, returns 0.0.